# Can we have multiple callout in timeline chart for single point?

Tags: highcharts

Can we have multiple callout in timeline chart for single bar?
for reference please look into attached spac[multiple callout spac][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJpug.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the second label as an annotation and customize&style it for your needs.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yx68cd91/

```
  annotations: [{
    labelOptions: {
      shape: 'connector',
      align: 'right',
    },
    labels: [{
      point: 'test',
      text: 'test of the annotation'
    }],
  }],
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations

Comment: I am using below given code for annotations in https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yx68cd91/  but it is sowing only one for first one , How we can show multiple annotations for more then 1 bar and ?
annotations: [
    {draggable: '',
        labelOptions: {
    shape: 'callout', align: 'right',
  },
  labels: [{
    point: 'test', text: 'test of the annotation'
  }]
    }, 
 {
        draggable: '',
        labels: [{
    point: 'zest', text: 'test of the annotation'
  }]
    }
 ]

Comment: I think that everything is explained very well in the API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations.labels Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uj7xqpb1/